# error accessing enum in class

Tags: c++, enums

I am working with the [CI2CV face library](http://face.ci2cv.net/) and I have a compilation error at this line:

```
int t = IOBinary::PAW;
```

the error message is :

> 'IOBinary::PAW' is ambiguous ' Candidates are: '

here is the class `IOBinary` definition

```
 class IOBinary : public IO{
  public:

    enum{PDM3D= IO::DUMMY_LAST_DONT_USE+1,PAW,PATCH};

    static void ReadMat(std::ifstream& s,cv::Mat &M);
    static void WriteMat(std::ofstream& s,cv::Mat &M);

    static std::vector<cv::Mat> LoadMatList(const char* fname);


  };
```

here is the class `IO` declaration:

```
class IO{
  public:
    enum{PDM3D = 0,PAW,PATCH,MPATCH,CLM,FDET,FCHECK,MFCHECK,TRACKER,TPS,AAM_POIC,PDM2D,AAM_POIC_F,SINIT,LINPATCH,CLP,CLD,TRACKER4,NONLINPATCH,MIXPATCH,CLM3,CLMix,PRA,ATM_PO,LBPHISTPATCH,FACEPREDICTORPRA,FACEPREDICTORKSMOOTH,MYFACETRACKER,MYFACETRACKERPARAMS,REGOCHECK,MVREGOCHECK,SHAPEPREDICTORLIST, SHAPEPREDICTOR, SHAPEEXPMAP, 
     DUMMY_LAST_DONT_USE};
  };
```

what can I do to solve this ?  Sorry if the question is too trivial.

**EDIT** here is the error message
[image: Error Message]

Comment: The error message certainly says "could be... or ...." in the following lines.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore after "could be" it is just blank, nothing there.

Comment: Post the full error message please.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, that is it, I will post a screenshot now

Comment: then post the full enum from where `IO::DUMMY_LAST_DONT_USE` comes from, and for that matter, the entire class decl for `IO` and `IOBinary`.

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi The compiler usually reports what declarations are ambiguous. So show the complete compiler message.

Comment: the sub class and the super class both has the enum value `PWD`, but this is supposed to be a tested library and this is the release version , how can I fix that without affecting the rest of the library ?

Comment: Based on what you've posted, it shouldn't be broken: [**See It Live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee206b5790940730) (assuming Coliru ever resurrects itself).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I will try to find the missing piece, thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 2):

I was working with eclipse.
I just cleaned the peoject and restarted Eclipse, now it is working fine.
<sub>I feel ashamed of asking this question before trying that (facepalm)</sub>

Comment: Sometimes even the best IDEs commit mistakes like that because C++ is extremely hard to parse/interpret and when all this is combined with "smart caching of IDEs": things can go wrong easily. In my opinion eclipse is not the best option to do C++ development. On Mac try Xcode, on linux you should give code::blocks a try and on windows Visual Studio is just awesome and it has free express editions.